# How to add Account-dashboard menu to newsletter/manage/ page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, xml, menu, newsletter

I tried to add the **Account dashboard menu** on the left side in `newsletter/manage/` page.

The phtml for this menu is `/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml`

Account dashboard menu it's added like this:

```
 <reference name="left">
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

Does anyone know in which xml I need to add this block to appears on the newsletter/manage page?

Comment: Can please Specify more clearly about your question by post image or code @Alin Lupoiu

Comment: please confirm http://prntscr.com/fkh9dt  ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by adding this in my local.xml:

```
<newsletter_manage_index translate="label">
  <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
<reference name="content">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
 </reference>
<reference name="left">
          <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigations" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>
</reference>
</newsletter_manage_index>
```